# joining three lists to plot data with errors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have three lists:

```
x = {x1, x2, ...},
y = {y1, y2, ...},
yErr = {y1Err, y2Err, ...}
```

that I want to join into the following format:

```
{{{x1, Around[y1, y1Err]}, {x2, Around[y2, y2Err]}, ...}}
```

How can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps

```
MapThread[{#1,Around[#2,#3]}&,{x,y,yErr}]
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: fabulous! just a typo correction: MapThread

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
{#, Around @ ##2} & @@@ Transpose[{x, y, yErr}]
```

or

```
Transpose[{x, Around @@@ Transpose[{y, yErr}]}]
```